# I want to use spread operator to add data to my array

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutability

I want to use spread operator to add data to my array. This works when its an object

```
{
  ...state,
  selections: {
    ...state.selections,
    [action.data.type]: action.data
  }
```

But when its an array

```
{
  ...state,
  selections: {
   ...state.selections,
   [action.data.type]: [] // Every time i save something it should end up here
}
```

i was thinking of

```
{
  ...state,
  selections: {
    ...state.selections,
    [action.data.type]: [
        ...state.selections[action.data.type], 
        action.data]
}
```

But it doesnt work because ...state.selections[action.data.type] its non-iterable instance.

This is what i want to accomplish

```
state: {
   selections { 
       products: ["a", "b"]
   }
}
```

I have tried to look into https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns

Comment: Can you show the complete structure of: state / selections / action.data ? Otherwise it is not easy to understand where you want to go

Comment: ofc. I just thought it was obvious that i wanted to populate state with the object selections that have a property that have an array of items =)

Comment: Your code should work fine as long as `state.selections[action.data.type]` has an inital value of type array (most cases an empty array). Else it would not be iterable inside an array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Easwar i thought it was set at the same time? So it would be iterable? Since the action.data.type is set with different values i cant interpret

Comment: It works then products are set as an empty array. So how can i acchive it to be set without first declared it?

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of the `spread` operator should be fine. I am quite sure the problem is, that you try to add `action.type` which in the case of your small example would be `state.selections` with non-iterable type `object`.

```js
// example
const x = { a: 1, b: { c: []}}
const y = {...x, b: { [x.b.c] : [...x.b.c, 1] }}

console.log(y);
```

Comment: It seems to be correct. Se commets above. Thanks for the input

Comment: Since we do not know your exact data, we can't tell you where your logical error comes from. Please check whether your `action` has a key for the product name or whatever. But using `action.type` should be logically wrong.

Comment: its action.data.type so this type is an type i send with my data. Its correct and it works as i say in my first sentence. Its when i try to add it to an array it doesnt work so the fix is that the "products" is not set to an empty array so products should be set to products: []

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
{
  ...state,
  selections: {
    ...state.selections,
    [action.data.type]: Array.isArray(state.selections[action.data.type])
        && [
        ...state.selections[action.data.type], 
        action.data]
        || [
        state.selections[action.data.type], 
        action.data]
}
```

Comment: I like your idea but the first time this is run i get [undefined, a] second run i get [undefined, a, b] so its doing something funky

Answer (score 0):

If `state.selections[action.data.type]` have initial value of `[]` when its an array this should work.

It would be much easier if you show example of the `payload` and the `initialState`.

Is `action.data` always an object ?

```
{
  ...state,
  selections: {
    ...state.selections,
    [action.data.type]: Array.isArray(state.selections[action.data.type])
      ? [...state.selections[action.data.type], action.data]
      : action.data
}
```